# PHP: Return value declaration in namespaces

Tags: php, php-7

I recently started learning PHP and since I'm used to strongly typed languages (C++, Java) I would really prefer to make use of type hinting and return type declarations. However when I'm trying to use return type declaration for primitives I get a fatal error, stating that my function does not return the correct type.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Bar {

    public function bar() : boolean {
        return true;
    }

}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->bar();

?>
```

This will cause a fatal error, stating that Bar::bar does not return a value of Foo\boolean type. So I tried resorting to the global namespace by changing the function prototype to:

```
public function bar() : \boolean
```

But then I got a fatal error stating that my function does not return a value of type boolean. I guess PHP is looking for a type called boolean in the global namespace and not for the primitive type. Great, so how am I supposed to indicate that I want my function to return a value of the primitive type boolean?

Comment: The type is `bool` not `boolean`.

Comment: You should also put `declare(strict_types=1);` as the first line of each file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type hint for a Boolean value is actually `bool`. Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Bar {
    public function bar() : bool {
        return true;
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->bar();
```

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid. Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: Nah, it's not stupid :) PHP allows classes to start with a lower-case letter, and until it started checking scalar type hints it was very common to see `bool` type-hinted as `boolean` (in comments). This is another case of a gotcha where the tooling can do little to help you spot an error.